# Rename Liquibase changelog tables with spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, liquibase

I'm using **Liquibase (v 3.5.3)** together with **Spring Boot (v 1.5.3)**.

I want to change liquibase changelog tables names using spring boot properties file.

The only way I found to do this is setting **liquibase.databaseChangeLogTableName** and **liquibase.databaseChangeLogLockTableName** system properties to override default table names.

Is there any alternative way to override default liquibase table names using spring boot properties file instead of setting system properties?

Answer (score 14):

Since this is 1 year old and still the first google result i found for this question:

For around spring boot 2.1.x (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/15544 last response) setting those properties works for me:

```
spring.liquibase.database-change-log-lock-table=MY_CUSTOM_DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK
spring.liquibase.database-change-log-table=MY_CUSTOM_DATABASECHANGELOG
```

Answer (score 7):

Have the same issue and manage to resolve it by overwriting liquibase global configuration. To get *databaseChangeLogTableName* & *databaseChangeLogLockTableName* liquibase create *LiquibaseConfiguration* instance and initialize all default parameters, but you can overwrite those parameters using next code.
Below is my Liquibase configuration file and properties.

**application.properties**

```
## Liquibase default properties
application.local.database.liquibase.tag = application-integration
application.local.database.liquibase.change.log.table.name = DATABASE_CHANGE_LOG
application.local.database.liquibase.change.log.lock.table.name = DATABASE_CHANGE_LOG_LOCK
application.local.database.liquibase.should.run = true
application.local.database.liquibase.change.log = classpath:database/application-database-changes.xml
```

**Spring Boot configuration**

```
import liquibase.configuration.GlobalConfiguration;
import liquibase.configuration.LiquibaseConfiguration;
import liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase;
... other dependencies...

@Configuration
public class LocalDatabaseLiquibaseConfig {

@Autowired
@Qualifier(ApplicationComponentNames.LOCAL_DATA_SOURCE)
private DataSource localDatabaseDataSource;

@Value("${application.local.database.liquibase.change.log.table.name}")
private String localDatabaseLiquibaseChangeLogTableName;

@Value("${application.local.database.liquibase.change.log.lock.table.name}")
private String localDatabaseLiquibaseChangeLogLockTableName;

@Value("${application.local.database.liquibase.tag}")
private String localDatabaseLiquibaseTag;

@Value("${application.local.database.liquibase.should.run}")
private boolean isLocalDatabaseLiquibaseShouldRun;

@Value("${application.local.database.liquibase.change.log}")
private String localDatabaseLiquibaseChangeLog;
    
    @Bean
    public SpringLiquibase liquibase() {
        // Overwrite default liquibase table names by custom
        GlobalConfiguration liquibaseConfiguration = LiquibaseConfiguration.getInstance().getConfiguration(GlobalConfiguration.class);
        liquibaseConfiguration.setDatabaseChangeLogTableName(localDatabaseLiquibaseChangeLogTableName);
        liquibaseConfiguration.setDatabaseChangeLogLockTableName(localDatabaseLiquibaseChangeLogLockTableName);
    
        SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
        liquibase.setDataSource(localDatabaseDataSource);
        liquibase.setShouldRun(isLocalDatabaseLiquibaseShouldRun);
        liquibase.setChangeLog(localDatabaseLiquibaseChangeLog);
        liquibase.setTag(localDatabaseLiquibaseTag);
    
    return liquibase;
    }
}
```

**Updated (Liquibase v 4.x.x)**

In version 4.x.x Liquibase introduced option to overwrite table names without overwriting global configuration, now it is part of SpringLiquibase class, checkout update java configuration example.

```
        @Bean
        public SpringLiquibase liquibase() {
            SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
            liquibase.setDataSource(localDatabaseDataSource);
            liquibase.setShouldRun(isLocalDatabaseLiquibaseShouldRun);
            liquibase.setChangeLog(localDatabaseLiquibaseChangeLog);
            liquibase.setTag(localDatabaseLiquibaseTag);
            
            liquibase.setDatabaseChangeLogTable(localDatabaseLiquibaseChangeLogTableName);
            liquibase.setDatabaseChangeLogLockTable(localDatabaseLiquibaseChangeLogLockTableName);
        
            return liquibase;
        }
```